# redirect https:// to https://www in IIS 8

Tags: redirect, iis, ssl, https, web-config

Suppose I have a site http://www.example.com which was 301 redirect from http://example.com to http://www.example.com.

Now after Google's recent update about using SSL for better rankings, I decided to use SSL.

I am using below code in `web.config` to 301 redirect to https

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

now its redirecting 301 all requests http://www.example.com and http://example.com to https://www.example.com

**but it's not redirecting https://example.com to https://www.example.com**

I want to do this for only one canonical version as many SEO authority sites suggested.

If I use Plesk builtin functionality to redirect all non www to www, then it does double redirect.

How can I do this, Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try a second rule to enforce the www, such as:

```
<rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^https://(?!www)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The condition you have on your rule will stop it firing for a https request such as https://example.com.

---

**Version #2** Try putting this before your other rule, the stopProcessing should stop it going circular.

```
<rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will test it will let you know.

Comment: How did it go? Was it ok?

Comment: No it's now working, may be because of CACHE_URL.. its giving error

Comment: anymore suggestion please?

Comment: I'm not near a dev environment this weekend. :-( What's the exact error your getting? I've used a variant of that rule OK before,.. maybe I've typoed in the answer.

Comment: oh then I won't disturb you, enjoy your weekend. I will comment here again on a working day. Thanks